# How to find row which has the minimum overall distance from the other rows of the pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, distance

I have pandas `dataframe` as follow:

```
df:


Unnamed: 0   0      1      2      3      4
0 -527.0  143.0  143.0  248.0 -952.0
1 -527.0  143.0  143.0  248.0 -955.0
2 -527.0  143.0  143.0  248.0 -955.0
```

I use  `mlpy.dtw_std` to compute distance matrix between rows:

```
dm = pdist ( df, lambda u,v: mlpy.dtw_std ( pd.Series ( u ).dropna ().values.tolist (),pd.Series ( v ).dropna ().values.tolist (), dist_only=True ) )
 distance_matrix=scipy.spatial.distance.squareform(dm)
```

How can I find row index (the first colomn (`Unnamed: 0`)) which has the minimum overall distance from the other members of the dataframe?

here is the distance_matrix:

```
[[ 0.  3.  3.]
 [ 3.  0.  0.]
 [ 3.  0.  0.]]
```

Comment: Once you get the overall distance per row, say you name it `dist`, something like this will do it: `df.loc[df.dist == min(df.dist)]`, however I can't replicate your distance matrix, I get the following error: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'dtw_std'`.

Comment: it is from `mlpy` library

Comment: Actually it will be super helpful if you share what your `dm` looks like. That way I don't have to recalculate it.

Comment: No need to compute the distance matrix, what if i have some row having the min value, and I want only one row as an answer

Comment: I have added the distance_matrix value

Comment: I believe `type(dm)` returns `numpy.ndarray`, correct? If so my answer should work as is; if not, please let me know what it returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first convert your distance matrix into a `numpy` array if it isn't already so, and then

```
df['dist'] = dm.mean(axis = 0)
```

to save the row-wise average distances as a column, and then

```
df[df.dist == min(df.dist)]
```

is going to give you the row with minimum average distance to others. To get the index, you can select only the first column like so:

```
df[df.dist == min(df.dist)].iloc[:,0]
```